# Alternative Representation for Energy Levels and Energy Level Density

Tags: plotting, graphics, code-request, broken-code

I need to show the energy level density around the local maximum of this double-well potential. I can do it using the following:

```
a0 = 0.02; a1 = 0.64; L = 10;
U[x_] := a0*x^4 - a1*x^2 + a1^2/(4 a0)
vals = NDEigenvalues[{-1/2 Laplacian[u[x], {x}] + U[x]*u[x], 
    DirichletCondition[u[x] == 0, True]}, u[x], {x, -L, L}, 25, 
   Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", {"MeshOptions" \
-> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.001}}}}];

Show[ Plot[{vals}, {x, -L, L}, PlotRange -> {Automatic, {-1.0, 15.0}},
   ImageSize -> 500, RotateLabel -> False, 
  FrameLabel -> {{"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(E\), \(n\)]\)", "U(x)"}, {"x",
      None}}, PlotTheme -> "Scientific"], 
 Plot[U[x], {x, -L, L}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Directive[Darker[Green], Thickness[0.005]]}, 
  Filling -> Axis, FillingStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.9], White]]]
```

[image]

> **1.** The above diagram serves the purpose; however, I require
> another representation using the density of states. The graph should
> look more or less like a Gaussian curve around the energy value of the
> hilltop. How do we plot that graph?

I have plotted the `Differences[vals]` using `ListLinePlot` as shown in the figure below. However, I believe there must be a better way to represent the energy level density around the hilltop of the double well. Besides, the *x-axis* in this graph makes no sense as it contains "*number of differences*".

[image]

> **2.** How can the energy levels be plotted with vertical lines, the
> energy spread along the horizontal line instead of the vertical, so
> that it can look like an energy spectrum through a spectrometer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably looking for [`SmoothHistogram`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SmoothHistogram.html).

```
SmoothHistogram[vals]
```

[image]

And you can use [`ListPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPlot.html) for vertical lines.

```
ListPlot[{#, 1} & /@ vals, Filling -> Bottom, PlotMarkers -> "", FillingStyle -> Thick]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Domen. Just one more query, is there a way to make these vertical lines colourful? Different colours for each line? `PlotStyle` and `ColorFunction` is not working

Comment: Just plot each of them as a separate list: `ListPlot[{{#, 1}} & /@ vals, Filling -> Bottom, PlotMarkers -> "", FillingStyle -> Thick]`. Also, note that `SmoothHistogram` takes the kernel size as the second argument, for example: `SmoothHistogram[vals, 0.5]`

Comment: Thank you so much @Domen